# Compile and link Fortran and C with ifort and icc

Tags: c, compilation, fortran, icc, intel-fortran

I'm switching from gcc to Intel ifort and icc.

The Fortran code is mostly legacy, likewise the the rest of the system.

The main program is written in C. It handles the I/O and passes everything to a Fortran subroutine.

For now I compile the Fortran part with:

```
cd fortran   
ifort -I../inc -debug full -c *.[fF]
cd ..
```

For C and linking I tried:

```
icc  -ansi -static -debug full -Wall -o testout \
     -I./inc -L./lib\
     main.c \
     fortran/*.o  \
     -lifcore -limf -lm\
```

this gives me:

```
ld: cannot find -lm
ld: cannot find -lm
ld: cannot find -lc
ld: cannot find -ldl
ld: cannot find -lc
```

This is mostly copied from the former bash script to compile with gcc.

Comment: the are introduced wit `-static`. As far as i understand it i need those to link the c standart lib static to redistribute this programm to useres without the Intel compiler.

Comment: Try `locate m` and see what path it gives. If it finds the library then add that in the `-L` option of yours. If it doesnt find then you need manually find `m` and add that.

Comment: m seems to be the standart math lib for C. So it is not in my working dir.

Comment: Have you run the `compilervars.sh` script before using `ifort` and `icc`?

Comment: @Sagar Masuti : ``locate libm.a`` corresponds to ``-lm`` linked statically and ``locate libm.so`` without the static flag.

Comment: i did `compilervars.sh intel64`

Comment: @AlexanderVogt apperently not. I didn't install the compiler. I now run the script and it fixed some parts. Changing `static` to `static-intel` does the trick. but i guess there are now still some dependencies to some lib left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-static` flag will link *all* the libraries statically. In that case you need to have a static version (the `.a` files) of every library. For example, using `-lm` will search for `libm.a`. Those libraries are not installed by default, but may be in the `-dev` or `-devel` packages of your distribution.
If you only want to link statically the Intel libraries, then you should use `-static-intel`.

A good trick to avoid static linking is to:

1) Dynamically link your program with `-static-intel` and `-Wl,-rpath=./lib`

2) Use `ldd` to find which libraries your program needs

3) Create a directory `lib` where you copy all the required dynamic libraries

4) Instead of distributing your code as a single static binary you can disrtibute it as a binary + the lib directory (assuming the licenses of the libraries permit it).

Finally, if you need to try more things, I have succeeded to link an Intel Fortran file with gcc using this command:

```
$ gcc fortran_file.o c_main_file.o -lifcore -lirc -lcomposerxe_gen_helpers_core_2.3
```

hope this helps...

Comment: I changed `static` to `static-intel` but without `-Wl, rpath=./lib` and now it works. But wont i have some dependencies now?

Comment: @why.n0t : Yes, but you can put the dependencies in the lib directory. The ``-Wl, rpath=./lib`` adds the lib directory to the default path where to search for dynamic libraries.

Comment: @why.n0t : Singularity (http://gmkurtzer.github.io/singularity/) is also a possibility to solve your dependency problems.